# How to replace pattern text to other text contains elements of basic text

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace some text to other text which contains elements of basic text.

For example:

```
text text
blabla HYPERLINK "mailto:x@x.com"x@x.com
text text
```

I want to replace `HYPERLINK "mailto:x@x.com"x@x.com to <a href="x@x.com">x@x.com</a>`

So the result should be:

```
text text
blabla <a href="x@x.com">x@x.com</a>
text text
```

How can I do that using Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do this:

```
String str = "text text\n" +
    "blabla HYPERLINK \"mailto:x@x.com\"x@x.com\n" +
    "text text";

str = str.replaceAll("HYPERLINK \\\"mailto:(.*?)\\\"\\1", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");     
System.out.println(str);
```

EDIT:

You could possible take a cue from the hyperlink markdown used here at SO and do the following for a more generalised solution:

```
String str = 
    "text text\n" +
    "blabla (mailto:x@x.com)[this email] or (mailto:x@y.com)[x@y.com]\n" +
    "text (http://www.google.com/)[this is google] text";

str = str.replaceAll("\\((.*?)\\)\\[(.*?)\\]", "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");       
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: And what if I want to match the pattern and as result have <a href="mailto:x1@x.com">x@x.com</a> or <a href="x.com">the page</a>. I try this one: HYPERLINK \"[mailto:]*?(.*?)\"\\1 and it doesnt work with "http://x.com" or any url

Comment: So you would like something that can parse `HYPERLINK "url"link_name` into `<a href="url">link_name</a>`?  I think the problem that you have is with spaces in `link_name`, for example, if I had `HYPERLINK "www.google.com"This is Google but not this` (how would you know that `This is Google` is part of the link but `but not this` isn't?

Comment: That is good clue. But now I have basic problem with general pattern for url with "mailto:" and without it, and also how to extract "url" and "link_name" in both cases

Comment: For text "asd HYPERLINK \"mailto:xxx@x.com\"some_email bbbbb HYPERLINK \"http://www.asd.com\"some_page dfgdfg" when I use basicText.replaceAll("HYPERLINK \\\"(.*?)\\\"(.*?)", "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>"); and now $2 is add after </a> tag, not before it: asd <a href="mailto:xxx@x.com"></a>some_email bbbbb <a href="http://www.asd.com"></a>some_page dfgdfg. It's weird. Can you help me again? I try but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: The problem is that your second group `(.*?)` matches no characters, so $2 is blank, and the some_page etc are not considered part of the match.  You'd need decide on a rule that can separate what's part of some_page or not.  For example in the above, you could decide that links shouldn't include spaces, so you could do `(\\\S+)` (one or more non-whatspace characters) for your second group.

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick... (nice challenge :-))

```
public static void parse() {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)HYPERLINK \"mailto:(.*)\"(\\S*)(.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("blabla HYPERLINK \"mailto:x@x.com\"x@x.com");
    if (m.matches()) {
        String processed = m.group(1) + "<a href=\"" + m.group(2) + "\">" + m.group(3) + "</a>" + m.group(4);
        System.out.println(processed);
    }
}
```